# Integrals and Intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus

I was reading the following article http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1259 regarding derivatives and integrals. In the first part of the **Integrals** when the author is explaining the derivative of the Area Function he defined he mentions that the Area from $x$ to $x+h$ is the same as the area of a rectangle with length $h$ and height of some value between the range of $f$ on $[x,x+h]$ The author appeals to the intermidiate value theorem as why this is true. But I am really confused and unable to understand why the area is the same if a select any value for the height that is between that domain. Sorry I can't be more clear I know that to understand my question you have to read that part of the article but I don't know how to put a graph here.

Comment: Triangle? That should say rectangle.

Comment: My mistake, thanks I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(z)$ is continuous and non-negative for $z\in [x,x+h]$, with $h>0$.

Let  $S$  be the region bounded by the axis $A=\{(z,0):z\in R\}, $ by the vertical lines $L_1=\{(x,y):y\in R\}$ and $L_2=\{(x+h,y):y\in R\}$, and by the graph of $f$.

Let $S_m$ be  the region  bounded by $A$, by $L_1$ and by $L_2$, and by the horizontal line $\{(z,m):z\in R\}, $ where $m=\inf \{f(z):z\in [x,x+h]\}$.

Let $S_M$ be the region bounded  by $A$, by $L_1$ and by $L_2$, and by the horizontal line $\{(z,M):z\in R\}$, where $M=\sup \{f(z):z\in [x,x+h]$.

Then $S_m\subset S \subset S_M.$ Therefore    $h m=Area(S_m)\leq Area(S)\leq Area(S_M)=h M.$ So we have  $$m\leq \frac {1}{h} Area(S)\leq M.$$

Since $f$ is continuous we have $\{f(z):z\in [x,x+h]\}=[m,M]$. (This is the intermediate-value-property of a continuous function.) Now since $\frac {1}{h} Area(S)\in [m,M]$ there must be at least one $c\in [x,x+h]$ with $f(c)=\frac {1}{h} Area(S)$, that is, $$h f(c)=Area(S).$$

Remark: The continuity of $f(z)$ for $z\in [x,x+h]$ also ensures that the real numbers $m$ and $M$ exist. In fact the continuity of $f(z)$ for $z\in [x,x+h]$ implies that $m=\min \{f(z):z\in [x,x+h]\}$ and that $M=\max \{f(z):z\in [x,x+h]\}.$

Comment: I have one question, are $S$,$Sm$ and $SM$ sets right? I am a little confused with the difference of for example the region $Sm$ and $Area(Sm)$

Comment: Yes they are subsets of the plane . $S_m$ and $S_M$ are rectangles,

Comment: One last question and maybe is a dumb one but I am trying to understand it correctly. Because $Sm$ is a subset of $S$ which means that has less elements that is why $Sm$ has a smaller area than $S$ or am I incorrect? I am new with this kind of definitions or explanation using sets and apologize for my ignorance

Comment: Any reasonable definition of area ought to say that if one piece of land  is either equal to or entirely a part of another piece, then its area cannot be more.